# SetState on navigate w/ conditional location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Why isn't `state = { pageIndex: 0 }` updating as per `this.handlePageIndex()` on Gatsby `navigate`, whilst it will during mount on a browser refresh?

```
state = { pageIndex: 0 };

componentDidMount() {
  this.handlePageIndex();
}

// Have tried but doesn't seem necessary.
// componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
//   const { location: prevLocation } = prevProps;
//   const { location } = this.props;
//   if (!prevLocation && location) {
//     this.handlePageIndex();
//   }
// }

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.handlePageIndex();
}

handlePageIndex = () => {
  const { location } = this.props;
  if (location.pathname === '/') {
    this.setState({ pageIndex: 0 });
  } else if (location.pathname === '/slide-two/') {
    this.setState({ pageIndex: 1 });
  } else if (location.pathname === '/slide-three/') {
    this.setState({ pageIndex: 2 });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add `componentDidUpdate` or `static getDerivedStateFromProps` to handle location change.

Note that `componentDidUpdate` will also fire on state change so you should check if `prevLocation !== location` before setting state there, otherwise you'll end up with infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, it was a simple mistake as you mentioned `!prevLocation && location` should have been `prevLocation !== location`.